# How to solve error (10060) for connecting AWS-RDS MYSQL?

Tags: amazon-rds

I have hosted website from aws platform and I have used Aws Rds mysql database. I am trying to connect to database from mysql workbench but it is showing error 
"Cannot Connect to Database Server" error (10060).

I have created the database following the steps in at this link:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information. Error 10060 means that RDS refused your connection attempt.

Comment: I have created this database and I can login first time but from second login it shows this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally.

Follow the steps given below.

Step1 - First find your machine's public IP address.

Step2 - Go to your EC2 instance and from your EC2 instance go to security groups.

Step3 - In your security groups find your database group id, group name and vpc id and select it.

Step4 - On selecting it you will find "Description, Inbound, Outbound, Tags" these four tabs.

Step5 - Select Inbound tab and go to edit and then click on add rule.

Step6 - Keep "Type, Protocol, Port Range, Source" same as above , in IP address section add your machine's **"public"** IP address and then save.

Step7 - Refresh EC2 instance and your MY SQL RDS database and after 5-10 minutes try reconnecting from your MYSQL Workbench.

It worked for me.